# Saving current view controller in swift

Tags: model-view-controller, uiviewcontroller, swift, navigation

I want to save the current view controller when I navigate to a new view controller so that if I navigate back to the previous view controller, the information is still present. What I'm doing right now is using segues to navigate between view controllers, using the prepare for segue function. However, this method creates a new view controller. I was thinking about using self.navigationcontroller.popviewcontroller, but will this restore the information from the previous view controller?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to go back, having the same instance of viewcontroller - Yes.

popviewcontroller will not create a new instance, but re-use created one. So yes, that's the way to go.

Comment: Is it better to use Segues to push and then the navigation controller to pop?